# Docker Django database connection error: UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF-8' and UNICODE 'UTF-16LE'

Tags: python, django, docker, pyodbc

UPDATE: I added some more lines to the error from odbc.log, as a user suggested that perhaps something else might be the problem.

I'm running into an issue with docker and django when trying to connect to a remote database (on a different server).

Using Python 3.4 and django 1.9.7. I can perform runserver just fine when running locally, and can connect using tsql or pyodbc.connect() in the docker container. However, when performing runserver on the docker container for the project, here is the error I receive:

> [ODBC][14][1604961520.418108][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
> Entry:
> Connection = 0x7f48618ecba0
> Window Hdl = (nil) 
> Str In = [UID={{UID}};PWD={{password}};DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER={{serverIP}};DATABASE={{databaseName}};unicode_results=True;][length = 110]
> Str Out = (nil)
> Str Out Max = 0 
> Str Out Ptr = (nil)
> Completion = 0
> UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF-8' and UNICODE 'UTF-16LE'
> [ODBC][14][1604961520.444358][SQLDriverConnectW.c][848]
> Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
> [ODBC][14][1604961520.444418][SQLDriverConnect.c][748]
> Entry: 
> Connection = 0x7f48618ecba0
> Window Hdl = (nil)
> Str In = [UID={{UID}};PWD={{password}};DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER={{serverIP}};DATABASE={{databaseName}};unicode_results=True;][length = 110]
> Str Out = 0x7f4865297db0
> Str Out Max = 2048
> Str Out Ptr = (nil)
> Completion = 0
> DIAG [08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source

This error is mentioned on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/known-issues-in-this-version-of-the-driver?view=sql-server-ver15 with the comment:

> There is more than one Driver Manager installed and your application is using the wrong one, or the Driver Manager was not built correctly.

I have tried everything I can think of and feel like I'm overlooking something really obvious here, but I've had no luck figuring out this error, or if I even have more than one driver being used (and if so how to fix that).

Here are other related setup files, perhaps someone will spot something or have an idea. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

**django database settings.py**

```
settings['DATABASES'] = {
        'default': {
            'HOST': '{{serverIP}}',
            'NAME': '{{databaseName}}',
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'USER': '{{UID}}',
            'PASSWORD': '{{password}}',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'unicode_results': True,
                'host_is_server': True
            }
        },
    }
```

**odb.ini**

```
[UAT_SERVER]
Description = UAT Database
Driver = FreeTDS
Database = {{databaseName}}
Servername = UAT_SERVER //I have also tried using the server IP here with no luck
Port = 1433
TDS Version = 4.2
```

**odbcinst.ini**

```
[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log

[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS Driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
TDS_Version = 4.2
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/freetds.log //This seems to do nothing, as no file is created.
ForceTrace = Yes
```

**freetds.conf**

```
[UAT_SERVER]
host = {{server ip}}
port = 1433
database= {{databaseName}}
tds version = auto
```

Comment: I might be wrong but it doesn't look like Unicode error as you have highlighted. It feels more of a information on how the connection is establlished

Comment: That's possible. This is my first go at setting up a docker container for a project and it's been a bumpy road. Is there more information I can give that might be helpful?

Comment: You could add [odbcinst](https://github.com/gordthompson/odbcinst) to your project and then have your application's startup code display (or log, or otherwise disclose) the results returned by `odbcinst.j()`. That might at least give an indication that unixODBC is set up as you expect.

Comment: I did so (needed to upgrade to python 3.5 in order to do so it turns out). And it does look like I was able to get a different error to crop up. I noticed that odbcinst.ini was not in an expected user directory, so on the container creation I copied it over. From there I got the error "Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist". I'm chasing this one down for the moment and will comment again later! Thank you for the help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to update this in case anyone is new to dockerizing a django project and runs into this issue like me. The issue I initially though (unicode issue) was not at all the problem. I dug a bit deeper and created a freetds log file, where I discovered the REAL error was that I had not defined the port in my django settings for my database connection.

As it turns out, despite using the default port (1433), you NEED to specify the port in your django settings database connection. Once I did this I was good to go!